# Updating static files of docker volume

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I have a Django website running in a docker image in my server, I need to update my static files without changing anything else, can I run a dockerfile just with that command or do `docker exec COMMAND` for that? What is the best practice in this case? If I run my dockerfile again, all the steps are in the cache memory and if I put the option of no-cache I am afraid that it will overwrite my media volume again, where I have images of the users. I think I have tried once without the cache but it did not update my volume of the static files.

```
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear
```

That is the command I think I need to run, but I am not sure if it works.

Comment: Where is the volume involved; how are you launching the container?  If you're hiding image content with a volume, the (old) contents of the volume will always take precedence when you run the container even if the underlying image is updated.

Comment: I use docker-compose and I have a volume for my static files, your comment explain a lot of things, maybe I need to delete the volume of static files and run again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was talking in the comments, and as David said, my old docker volume takes precedence, and it's overwriting my new static files in my django application. I solved this deleting and recreating my docker volume.